# Why does my phone on 6.0.1 download the entire app all over again when updating?

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow

I have 2 devices, my Cherry mobile One G1 running 6.0.1 (an Android One device) and my old Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 tablet running Jellybean 4.2.2.

When installing updates on my tablet, only the a small part of the update is downloaded [this discussion said they're called "delta"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51668/why-app-updates-download-entire-app-instead-of-only-updates). But when on my phone, it downloads the entire app all over again. It's fine for small apps, but some games have well over 100mb of data sometimes and it hurts my data allowance to update them.

Is it a feature of MM 6.0.1 or is it a bug on my phone?

Comment: Not an answer but a hint: If you're on a limited data plan you might want to download app-updates only over WiFi. You can set this behaviour in the Google Play Store -> Settings.

Comment: Have you observed this behavior on your phone for all apps? Not all apps support delta update, and usually it's the case for apps/games with [expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) (apps/games that exceed 100MB limit).

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, I didn't know about expansion files

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, it happens for all the apps on my phone. It's strange because on my tablet, only the delta gets downloaded for the same app. As mentioned below, one example is 9th Dawn II.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Store's App Updates [vary by device's Android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459887/google-play-displaying-my-app-version-as-varies-with-device). It's highly likely that the new updates being installed on your Android 6 device has huge changes in it to support latest Android APIs.

If you're downloading big games, there will be some [extra size](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)
 to be downloaded initially.
But if you're updating the app, it usually requires much less data.

Comment: I don't think that's it because I update the same apps on my tablet and on my phone. My tablet only downloads the delta while my phone downloads the entire thing. One recent example I can remember is 9th Dawn II.

Comment: I assumed you download/update the same apps on both devices. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post. Yes, I'm updating the same app on different devices. Your, theory about API support likely the case. Is there a way to confirm this?

Comment: @beeshyams your thoughts? :)